# Get LinkedIn user profile data using LinkedIn oauth2

Tags: java, authentication, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, spring-social-linkedin

I created an app on LinkedIn Developers, and I was able to get an access token when a user logged in.
The problem is that I can only get the ID, name, email and photo of the user.
I am unable to get the full details of the profile and even the link to the user's profile via (vanityName).

This is the scope I use: `scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress%20profile%20openid%20w_member_social%20email`

Can anyone help?

I tried different scopes and different prejection without success.

Comment: is your api public or private?

Comment: just testing it on localhost

Comment: no i meant to say. the linkedin api which you are using, is that public or private api?

Comment: were u able to resolve this? i am stuck with same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Profile fields are heavily restricted with the LinkedIn API. You can see an overview [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin%2Fconsumer%2Fcontext#retrieve-current-members-profile); essentially, you're getting the basic profile fields and for anything beyond that, you need to have special approval from LinkedIn. And per [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access#compliance-closed), the `r_compliance` permission is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use scopes:

- openid
- profile
- email